# Get class from string representation

Tags: python, import

Given some package that contains several modules, I want to write a method that gets a specific class from its name (`__name__`), however, it is not explicitly known what module contains the desired class. If the desired class is in the same module as the calling function, one may use:

```py
getattr(sys.modules[__name__], class_name)
```

If I know what module contains the desired class, I can use:

```py
import importlib
module = importlib.import_module('package_name.module_name')
my_class = getattr(module, class_name)
```

Is there some similar solution to my problem? One solution I can think of is to (1) find all modules in my package and (2) call `getattr` for each of them, however, `getattr` throws an exception if unsuccessful, so I am interested in a cleaner solution.

Comment: Run a for loop through all possible cases , and check for checking if the module has that class?

Comment: How can I check this?

Comment: You say package containing several modules, so package.module1, package.module2 etc? also how are you planning to find all modules in your package